# Como obtener respuesta ajax en una variable o alert

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando obtener la respuesta de mi petición ajax, pero no he podido con ello. Tengo este codigo que funciona perfectamente para enviar pero no me recibe la respuesta y me gustaria tener esa respuesta en un alert.

Aqui la petición ajax

```
   var url = "enviar.php";
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:{mesa:mesa,item:item,precio:precio},
            success: function(data)

            {
          $("#text").html(data);

            }
          });

            return false;
       });
     });
     </script>
```

Aqui un fragmento de mi php

echo 'Agregado';

Comment: Aquí tú indicas que muestre la respuesta del PHP en un elemento cuyo id es `text`: **`$("#text").html(data);`**. Si realmente hay un elemento con ese id en tu documento **y no hay error en la petición**, verás allí la respuesta del servidor. Si quieres verlo en un `alert` pones esto, justo debajo: `alert(data);` Si lo quieres en una variable: **`respuesta=data; alert (respuesta);`**. No obstante, tu petición debería implementar una función `fail`, para saber si hubo error en la petición. De paso, cambias el `success` por un `done`, ya que `success` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.

Comment: ok entiendo gracias...

Answer (score 1):

Amigo tu **ajax** esta perfecto lo único que creo es que el **php** no esta retornado información para ello tienes que retornar con `echo` espero te ayude saludos.

---

**PHP**

Prueba con este php simple y deberia darte como alert `"Hola mundo"`

```
<?php


 echo "Hola mundo"

?>
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

> **NOTA** Es una petición a un API de prueba.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En el ejemplo anterior usamos un ajax que nos retorna una [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) en pocas palabras el metodo `.then` seria lo mismo que el `success` de un **ajax** convencional.

> NOTA: Para el ejemplo se usa la function [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) que nos transforma un JSON a string para poder visualizarlo en el `alert`.

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué usas `then`  en lugar de `success`, ya que tu respuesta implica un cambio con respecto al código usado en la pregunta. Y... ¿si hay un error en la petición, cómo lo manejas? ¿Y por qué `JSON.stringify`? Creo que no se trata solamente de mostrar un código que funcione, si incorporas elementos nuevos en la respuesta deberías explicarlos... en la pregunta se plantea mostrar una respuesta de un texto simple, responder con un código que devuelve un JSON podría confundir más en vez de aclarar, sobre todo si está empezando con Ajax.

Comment: tienes toda la razón voy a cambiar la respuesta para mejorarla